# MVC4 how to set default url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on building a MVC4 web app and want to set specific URL I would like to use in the start point of my web application.

So I changed some values in RouteConfig.cs like this below.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{action}.mon/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "login", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

you may notify this, but I put a suffix after action name, so that I could invoke a controller, displaying the URL like " index.mon "

if I manually put "index.mon" after host address in URL bar, then it works just okay.
But when the app gets started automatically, it throws 403.14 error. ( "automatically start" means here that I ran this app by putting F5 key to run a temporary IIS server. )

the login controller looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Monarch815MVC.Controllers
{
public class loginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /login/

    public ActionResult index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult loginProcess(string id = "000000", string pass = "example", string scode = "co")
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> sessionData = null;

        String SqlCommand = "USP_LOGIN";

        DataSet UserInfo = dataController.ExecuteDataset(dataController.CONN_STRING, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SqlCommand, arParms);

        if (UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            sessionData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            for (int i = 0; UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].Table.Columns.Count > i; i++)
            {
                sessionData.Add(UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].Table.Columns[i].Caption, UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[i]);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

( let's forget about the loginProcess, I took off a few codes. )

Do I have to do something on returning phase in index() or on Web.config? or, RouteConfig.cs?

I have to use the suffix ".mon" to invoke controllers with it.

Comment: by putting .mon on there you are telling the routing to only route when the controller part of the url contains .mon.  In other words, you're doing the exact opposite of what you want.  Default actions do go to a specific url, they are the action that is performed when no url is given.

Comment: thanks for your comment, So how can I set the default action you mentioned above? I want my app to get started with "localhost/index.mon" How to do this?? that's what I'm asking :(

Comment: You didn't listen to what I said.  You are trying to make default actions do something they can't do.  A default action only says "Execute this action method on this controller if there is no url"  ie.. if you say `http://yoursite/`  (with nothing else).  Default actions do not make you redirect to a specific url.  Routes only interpret the current url and execute an action based on it.

Comment: Default actions don't produce such url, I got it. So I got rid of the defaults option in the route setting. What I still want to know, again, is that what kind of settings do I have to set in order to run my app with 'localhost/index.mon'...? need to modify Web.config or something?

Comment: I've googled on this, but setting start page is only I found so far. :(

Answer (score 0):

I could think of solving this issue by only using a hack. You might want to create a dummy action which will be the default action and upon being hit will redirect the request to your index.mon

i tried following, Please check if this helps you. Thanks.

In the **route config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultY",
                url: "{action}-mon/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "DefaultX2",
              url: "{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Startup", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
        }
```

In **controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Startup()
        {
            return RedirectToRoute("DefaultY", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        } 
    }
```

For me i used index-mon. index.mon was not working (something which i'l explore later, perhaps it relates to static files), but above code demonstrates the approach.

Hope that helps.